# Cycles - Material - Toon BSDF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is it possible to remove this effect from the *Toon BSDF*, *Diffuse*?

[image]

Comment: Can you describe "the effect" with words, just to be sure we understand correctly what you mean? The two circle seems to highlight different things. Also, why are you using cycles if you don't want path tracing features?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to remove the influence of the object on the lighting of the scene. To do this, mix the material of your object with a Transparent Shader, using a combination of the "Is Reflection Ray" and "Is Shadow Ray" outputs of a Light Path node as a Mix Factor. (Shadow Ray removes the shadow, Reflection Ray removes the light bounce - we want both, so we add them):

**With Shadows and Light Bounces**:
[image: With]

**Shadows and Light Bounces removed**:
[image: NotThere]

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks, no cycles and a light Area. No more influence of the objects. I solved the problem!
thank you all[image]